# ReactJs: Cannot update state on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fullcalendar, redux-saga, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to get the stored time zone from the redux state using useSelector and send it to the Full Calendar as props. But I get this error,

```
react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.tz is not a function
```

here's my function

```
export default function Schedule(){
    const { userTimezone } = useSelector((state) => state.settings)
    return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <FullCalendar
        nowIndicator
        timeZone={userTimezone}
        plugins={[timeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, momentTimezonePlugin]}
        initialView="timeGridWeek"
        headerToolbar={{
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
        }}
        editable
        selectable
        selectMirror
        dayMaxEvents
        weekends
        locales={allLocales}
        events={currentevents}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

when I console log the userTimezone I am getting the desired string, when I enter the string manually on the timeZone prop, it works.. It is only when I pass the variable I get errors what could be the reason for this?

DETAILED ERROR:

```
MomentNamedTimeZone.timestampToArray
C:/Users/user/Desktop/frontend/src/main.ts:11
   8 | // explicit API
   9 | export { EventSourceApi } from './api/EventSourceApi'
  10 | export { EventApi, buildEventApis } from './api/EventApi'
> 11 | export { CalendarApi } from './CalendarApi'
  12 | export { formatDate, formatRange, FormatDateOptions, FormatRangeOptions } from './formatting-api'
  13 | export { ViewApi } from './ViewApi'
  14 | export * from './api-type-deps'

DateEnv.timestampToMarker
C:/Users/user/Desktop/frontend/src/datelib/env.ts:422
  419 |   } if (this.timeZone === 'UTC' || !this.namedTimeZoneImpl) {
  420 |     return new Date(ms)
  421 |   }
> 422 |   return arrayToUtcDate(this.namedTimeZoneImpl.timestampToArray(ms))
      | ^  423 | }
  424 | 
  425 | offsetForMarker(m: DateMarker) {

DateEnv.createNowMarker
C:/Users/user/Desktop/frontend/src/datelib/env.ts:98
   95 | 
   96 | createNowMarker(): DateMarker {
   97 |   if (this.canComputeOffset) {
>  98 |     return this.timestampToMarker(new Date().valueOf())
      | ^   99 |   }
  100 |   // if we can't compute the current date val for a timezone,
  101 |   // better to give the current local date vals than UTC
```

Comment: The warning in the title doesn't match the question... Please correct it, or add the necessary details to your question as to why it's relevant

Comment: I have updated the question, please let me know if that's sufficient, I am not posting the full code as I am using a very huge stack with redux, redux-sagas, axios and apollo etc.. so it will take a lot of time to reproduce.

Comment: @WildThing You could try the following: `timeZone={userTimezone||'some valid timezone'}`

Comment: @HMR Thanks for the suggestion! Although here I am noticing that only the local and UTC are working, named timezones are not working for some reason, It is weird because it was working before and I have not made any major changes. If you see I have included the moment plugin aswell, please refer https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment-timezone-plugin